# Changing Password Policy in ZImbra

Tags: zimbra

I just noticed how bad the password policy is on a mailserver:
[image: Zimbra default password policy]

If I change these values for the default Class of Service, will existing users that don't meet the requirements be able to log in, or will they have to change their passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I remember running into this issue earlier. No, the old users will still be able to login, but I would suggest that you force a password reset for everyone.

You can find more details on [this thread](https://forums.zimbra.org/viewtopic.php?t=23457) from the Zimbra forums.

Comment: Thanks, I know I have to do it, but I think I’ll wait for a quiet day